# Why table is not printed correctly with echo?

Tags: php, html

I am following this tutorial to print the values of a submited file using echo in php.
Tutorial: http://www.learncomputer.com/tutorial-uploading-files-in-php/

```
<?php //Whole php code
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr><td>Client FileName: </td>
<td>" . $_FILES["fileName"]["name"] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>File Type: </td>
<td>" . $_FILES["fileName"]["type"] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>File Size: </td>
<td>" . ($_FILES["fileName"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Name of Temporary File: </td>
<td>" . $_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"] . "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Nevertheless, when I upload and submit an image, the following result is printed on screen

```
"; echo "Client Filename: " . $_FILES["fileName"]["name"] . ""; echo "File Type: " . $_FILES["fileName"]["type"] . ""; echo "File Size: " . ($_FILES["fileName"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb"; echo "Name of Temporary File: " . $_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"] . ""; echo ""; ?>
```

which is not the expected table with the name, type, size and name of temporary file as expected. I have even tried to replace the quotes " for ' but unsuccessfully. I don´t understand why is the semicolon at the beginning been printed and the code instructions ".$var." insted of the actual value of the variables

EDIT: My PHP version 7.2.1 and here is the html code with which I submit and call my php code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<!-- GOOGLE -->
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<!--<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer> 
</script> -->
<!-- GOOGLE -->
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Tops.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Ejemplo_botones.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Config.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<style>
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<nav>
    <a href="Topsitio.html"><img src="logo.png" class=top alt=""></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
        <li><a href="I.php">Iniciar Sesión</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<figure>
    <img src="shop.png" class=shop alt="">

</figure>
<div class="container">
    <div class="Pasos">
       <ul>
           <a href=""><li class="paso1 paso">Paso 1 </li></a>
           <a href=""><li class="paso">  Paso 2 </li></a>
           <a href=""><li class="paso"> Paso 3 </li></a>
           <a href=""><li class="paso"> Paso 4 </li></a>
           <a href=""><li class="paso5 paso"> Paso 5</li></a>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="registro"> 
    <p id="regi" class="titulo-registro">Cargar foto de Perfil</p>
    <div class="ringborder">
        <div class="ring">
            <i id="profile" class="fas fa-user-tie"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br><form action="upload_table.php " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="contenedor">
    <p>
        Elige una foto:</p>
                <input class="plus" type="file" name="fileName" id="file-5" class="inputfile inputfile-4" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" hidden>
                <label for="file-5"><figure  class="box"><svg id="upload" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="180" height="170" version="1.1">
                   <path id="upload" fill="white" heigthstroke="#f00" transform="scale(3.0)" d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"></path>
                    </svg></figure> 
                </label>

    </div>

    <br><input class="subir" type="submit" value="+ Subir foto">

    </form>
    <br><br>
    <div class="next">Siguiente</div>

</div>

<div class="first blau">
    <h1><span class="text">Articulos de gran calidad</span><span class="text2"> &nbsp  - &nbsp  Relojes y Pulseras</span></h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Look at the end of your first line more specifically where you have 3 `"`'s back to back

Comment: Did your top of .php file had a php tag? <?php

Comment: Please show us the complete file content, the file name and tell us what version of PHP you are using.

Comment: Or you forgot a `<?php` at the top of the file, or you don't have PHP installed/configured.

Comment: Isaac, yes that was the first I checked, but I have all quotes closed as seen up. Mahmoud of course I have "<?php" tag over and "?>" under the code

Comment: It looks like your PHP code isn't being executed. Do other PHP files work properly on the server you're using?

Comment: I've tested it in Laravel, and it's displaying well. Your PHP code isn't executed at all

Comment: Don´t Panic, yes all my other PHP files execute properly, I will check why this file may not be executing as well correctly

Comment: Please post the whole `upload_table.php` so we can see if it has some problems.

Comment: KeitelDOG, that´s the whole php code!

Comment: Ok now I see the `<?php` above.

Comment: Are you using Linux? And copied the file from Windows created file?

Comment: KeitelDOG, no I am using Windows 10

Comment: From the output it seems that PHP is not enabled for the file. It is not executed as a PHP script, but sent to the browser as is. You will see that when looking at the source view in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to try to put everything into `echo`. Let the HTML be just plain HTML and add the PHP data where needed.

```
// assuming you were already in PHP
?>
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Client Filename: </td>
<td><?php echo $_FILES['fileName']['name']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>File Type: </td>
<td><?php echo $_FILES['fileName']['type']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>File Size: </td>
<td><?php echo ($_FILES['fileName']['size'] / 1024); ?> Kb</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name of Temporary File: </td>
<td><?php echo $_FILES['fileName']['tmp_name']; ?></td></tr>
</table>
<?php // back into PHP if you need to for something else
```

Comment: Note also that this should be the preferred way due to less characters to process by php!

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug your PHP code, cause it seems correct.

The best way to start debugging is to try using fake static values in $_FILES to see what happen :

```
<?php

    $_FILES["fileName"] = [];
    $_FILES["fileName"]["name"] = 'test.jpg';
    $_FILES["fileName"]["type"] = 'image/jpg';
    $_FILES["fileName"]["size"] = 134767;
    $_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"] = '/tmp/temp_filename.jpg';


    echo "<table border=\"1\">";
    echo "<tr><td>Client Filename: </td>
    <td>" . $_FILES["fileName"]["name"] . "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>File Type: </td>
    <td>" . $_FILES["fileName"]["type"] . "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>File Size: </td>
    <td>" . ($_FILES["fileName"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Name of Temporary File: </td>
    <td>" . $_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"] . "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

If it doesn't work, copy one of your php file that work, put the same code in it, and replace the `upload_table.php` in it. Because if the start of your `upload_table.php` has BOM ([Byte Order Mark can cause display problem in PHP](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/utf-8-bom-and-php.53990/)), it will print some blank characters at the top, and possibly prevent php code execution. Or you can save the file utf8 without BOM. But I doubt this is related to BOM, bu you never know.